# Password protect master repository

Tags: git

We are using Git with three main branches Development, Test & Master in bare-repository.

We have many development environments all are having git repository. Everyone created development branch and works on that branch and push their code to Development branch in bare-repository.

Meanwhile we want to restrict the developers to push their code to Test & Master branch from their development branch.

Is there any way to protect bare-repository branches by using password.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) if you are using linux to host the repository.

Gitolite allows you to specify per user or groups of users what branches they can push to, and more.

> Gitolite is useful in any server that is going to host multiple git repositories, each with many developers, where "anyone can do anything to any repo" is not a good idea. Here're two examples to illustrate.

It uses ssh keys to identify users, and based on that decide what is allowed or not.

Comment: I second this.  Gitolite was easy to install and works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Or you change to a distributed pull-based approach:

Instead of having a branch for each team they *have their own repository*; with write-access to everything there.

Instead of a readonly master branch there is one main-repository that only a selected group of maintainers have write access to. Whenever you want something merged from the development repos into the main-repo, they'd have to notify the maintainers and have them do it.

I would also suggest using gitolite or Gitosis to manage the repositories easily (I myself have only used Gitosis, it's a breeze to set up and maintain).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot password protect a specific branch with "git only". It's all permissions, or none.

You can use gitolite which is really great to handle permissions, as said by Ikke.

An alternative more "hand made" is to use a pre-receive hook in your remote bare repository ( hooks/post-receive) to ask for a password.

You can do that with a simple shell script or use any language you want.